# Need help setting up a (Tomcat) web app in Eclipse for debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I've been using both eclipse and tomcat for years but have always deployed my web apps externally and never had a problem.  Now I'd like to use eclipse to debug my web app and I can't figure out how to make it work.  I started by trying to get my existing web app to deploy through eclipse but after hours of trying different things I decided to start fresh.  Unfortunately, I didn't get much further.  I'm hoping if I can figure out how things work with a fresh webapp I can get things to work on my existing.  Sorry, this will be long, but here are the steps I tried on the latest eclipse (Juno):

- Installed new version of tomcat 7.0.34 at /usr/java.
- In eclipse, used "servers" view to add server, pointing to the new install (I didn't add any resources because there weren't any available yet). Starting the server worked and got a 404 as expected at `http://localhost:8080/` ... then I stopped it.
- Created a new "dynamic web project", named it TomcatDebug, set the location to ~/tomcat-debug, chose the server just created above (the only one), chose default config, tomcat-debug is empty so chose defaults for build paths, defaults for module settings and had it generate web.xml.
- In the "tomcat-debug" folder it creates WebContent, build, and src.  I throw a sample "hello, world" index.html into WebContent.
- Now the project TomcatDebug is created so I try to run it, tell it to "run on server", and it goes to `http://localhost:8080/TomcatDebug/` but gives a 404.  I even try to add index.html but it still gives a 404.

This is about as basic as it can possibly get so what did I do wrong?

Continuing to try and figure this out I stop the server, change the server setting to "use tomcat installation", but still get a 404 in the same way when I restart.  I tried changing my module context path and still 404.

I'm completely stumped.  I believe I followed all the wizards as basically as possible.  Where did I go wrong?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Do you see the default root tomcat setup page?  I have never gotten a clean install of tomcat to serve static pages without some configuration of the web.xml file.

Comment: @BeenCoding2Long - I let the project wizard create the web.xml for me and inside it includes a welcome-file-list that includes index.html. However, I'm not even sure it is serving out of the WebContent folder (where the web.xml lives).

Comment: @BeenCoding2Long - Sorry, to answer your question better, `http://localhost:8080/` also returns a 404.

Comment: Have you checked if your project has been deployed?
You can view the deployment directory by double-clicking on your server in the Server view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't run tomcat through eclipse in a while, so can't answer that aspect of the question.  But, to get at the heart of what you're trying to do (debug a webapp in eclipse through tomcat), you shouldn't necessarily need to.  This may serve you instead:

**EDIT**:  Eh, look [here for instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing) ("Debugging" section).  The below is how I did it (JUNO and TC 7) and has an annoying quirk in point #1.

1. edit the startup.sh (assuming *NIX/OS X) - the last line will probably be

   `exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"`

   change this to

   `exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"`

   to activate [debugging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html).  (there are other ways to do this that may be better - i think tomcat/the VM may pause for listeners before proceeding, so when you aren't debugging this is not ideal)
2. Create a Debug Configuration in eclipse, under the "Remote Java Application" set.  Default port should be fine, and presumably host.  Choose your project.
3. Add sources of relevance to your debugging in the Source tab.
4. Start server and run your new debug configuration.  App should stop at breakpoints you've set.

Comment: Eh, are you sure? This looks like more for building tomcat in eclipse, not web apps in general.

Comment: Yep.  Ignore the link, if preferred.  My instructions are what I have successfully done to debug  my webapps in standalone tomcat.  (I've never built tomcat in eclipse.).  Tomcat doesn't fork the JVM process that I've seen, so if your JVM is started with debugging enabled, it shouldn't matter whether you are debugging TC or your webapp, anyway.  Also, this takes like 10 minutes, so its cheap to try.

Comment: Sorry, was busy then had a long holiday break, but this is what I ended up doing and it worked.  I'm curious though, what is the point of the "Apache Tomcat" debug configuration? No matter what I tried I couldn't get it to work but the "Remote Java Application" worked perfectly the first try. Hmm ...

Comment: I just basically replicated your steps and it worked out for me.  I'd chuck out there that maybe your settings are such that your app doesn't auto-publish - you could try manually publishing from the servers view.  But I dunno - I haven't worked with TC from within an eclipse-based IDE in a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click your index.html **Run As -> Run On Server** you will see Tomcat will automatically run the page.

Comment: As I explained, this wasn't working for me.  Thanks anyway, though.